Probability that Triangle on Ellipse is Acute
Consider an ellipse centered at the origin with width $2a$ and height $2b$. Choose points $A$, $B$, $C$ independently and uniformly distributed on the perimeter of the ellipse, and create $\triangle ABC$. What is the probability that $\triangle ABC$ is acute given $a$ and $b$?
The motivation behind this problem comes from a post discussing Random Triangles Inscribed in Cones and Cylinders. I was interested in the case of a cone, where an inscribed triangle in a cone could also be inscribed in an ellipse.
The case in which $a=b$ (circle) has already been discussed in Probability that the Triangle is Acute. One solution involved parametrizing the three points on a circle, and integrating the three dimensional region described by the constraints of the problem (angles are acute). A solution for the ellipse could possible involve the parametrization $(a\cos\theta_1, b\sin\theta_1), (a\cos\theta_2, b\sin\theta_2), \text{and } (a\cos\theta_3, b\sin\theta_3)$. However, the relationship between $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3$ and the angles of the triangle ($\gamma, \beta, \alpha$) is more complicated in an ellipse than the special case of a cirlce (inscribed angle theorem). This would make it hard to find conditions on $\theta_i$, and be able to integrate on the entire/permissible region.
This post, on how to Generate Random Points on Perimeter of Ellipse provides the method I used to randomly generate a triangle whose vertices lie on the perimeter of an ellipse, and numerically calculate the probabilities for pairs of $a,b$ values. Here is a heatmap of the probability that a randomly inscribed triangle an ellipse of width $2a$ and height $2b$ is acute for $a,b \in (0, 100]$:

The computations I used were very crude. Evidently, the probability that an inscribed triangle is acute is the same for ellipses with swapped $a,b$ values, leading to the symmetry. The case of $a=b$ has a 0.25 chance of being acute, as mentioned in the post linked above. I am hoping the solution is some three dimensional surface to describe the probability for the inputs $a,b$.
Thanks.

The probability only depends on the ratio $a/b$ (in fact, due to the symmetry, only on the absolute value of its logarithm), so you could produce a more informative graph by considering it as a function of one variable.

Even if you fix two of the points, it's hard to determine the exact probability of making an acute triangle, since it'll be an arc (or multiple) on the ellipse.
